# MySQL Connector/NET's MySqlCommand not using Parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datetime, parameterization

So I'm having some issues with the MySQL connector (specifically for .NET). Normally, I'd just not use parameterization -- although I realize that doing so leaves my program vulnerable to SQL injection.

Unfortunately, however, I can't just do that; I need to store an array of bytes (those which are derived from reading an image file on the client side of this program) into a MySQL database. Obviously, putting the byte array into the query string isn't going to work; that'll just put "`System.Byte[]`" into the array.

I've used parameterized queries before -- but only in [java](/questions/tagged/java). The following is my code, where `packet` is an object I've guaranteed will return correct data in all circumstances (for testing purposes, I've even added a driver class which has all hard-coded data) and the `Server` singleton's connection is guaranteed to be open and valid.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into `screenshots` (`playerId`, `serverId`, `data`, `uploadDate`, `uploadingUserId`) values(?playerId, ?serverId, \"?attachmentData\", \"?dateTime\", ?userId,)", Server.getSingleton().getDbManager().getConnection());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?playerId", packet.getPlayerId()); //string of an integer
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?serverId", packet.getServerId()); //string of an integer
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?attachmentData", packet.getAttachmentData()); //byte[]
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?dateTime", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?userId", packet.getUserId()); //string of an integer
cmd.executeNonQuery();
```

The issue I'm having is that the MySql Connector/NET seems to never replace the parameters with their values. I've tried instantiating a `new MySqlParameter` object, setting its `Value`, then calling `cmd.Parameters.Add(...)`, but that presents the same issue.

I took a look at the MySQL documentation, and it says to use `MySqlCommmand#Parameters.AddWithValue(string, object)`, and there are no other steps that I'm missing.

Whenever I attach Visual Studio's debugger to the process, it is visible that the parameters have all been added to the `Parameters` list property; however, when the query executes, the Just-in-Time Debugger halts execution and highlights the line with `cmd.executeNonQuery()` on it, saying that `'?dateTime' is not a valid value for column 'dateTime'` (where the column `dateTime` is of SQL type `DateTime`) or something to that extent.

This obviously means that the parameters are not being replaced with their values. `?dateTime` isn't a valid value for a `DateTime` field because it has to be in format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, so an exception is thrown by the Connector. But what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help -- I'm used to doing database-related things in Java (along with socket logic and the like), but this is a project for school which requires it be done in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those don't look like valid MySQL parameters; if you want named parameters, use `@yournamehere`, like so:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into `screenshots` (`playerId`, `serverId`, `data`, `uploadDate`, `uploadingUserId`) values(@playerId, @serverId, @attachmentData, @dateTime, @userId)", Server.getSingleton().getDbManager().getConnection());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playerId", packet.getPlayerId());
```

You also shouldn't quote a parameter; ADO.NET will do that as necessary, based off the target column's datatype.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html

Comment: Per your reference of MySQL's reference, it seems it's out-of-date -- I actually read that page myself; however, I also came across a version of MySQL Connector/NET's release notes for some version and it stated that the `@` had been changed to `?` to support users (for example, `user@localhost` would be invalid because it would attempt to find a parameter). There is, of course, a way to change parameters back to `@` by using a connection string option. I will, however, look into the quoting parameters.

Comment: Ugh, I feel so stupid for not trying to remove the quotes -- I'd assumed C# wouldn't be so nice to me. Removing them worked, but the parameters are escaped with `?`. Thanks!

Comment: @DanJesensky Hmm. The docs say "This option was deprecated in Connector/Net 5.2.2. All code should now be written using the '@' symbol as the parameter marker." - what version of the connector are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure where I read it anymore, but I remember seeing a bunch of questions on StackOverflow using `?` instead of `@` too. I'll edit my code to use `@` instead. Thanks again.