# Difference between "?" and "@" in visual basic

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I just want to ask what is the difference between ? and @ when inserting data to mysql in visual basic. So I have this query:

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, position) VALUES(?fname, ?lname, ?pos)"

cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?fname", TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?lname", TextBox2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pos", TextBox3.Text)
```

I first use the @param but it is not inserting data to mysql but when I use ?param it inserts data. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Please check your tags and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46617097/edit) the question to use appropriate ones.  (I think you probably want [vb.net] instead of [vba], and [visual-studio] and [visual-studio-2010] are definitedly inappropriate for this question.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691801/mysql-connector-nets-mysqlcommand-not-using-parameters

Comment: have you tried to use @ also in AddWithValue function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When CommandType is set to Text, the .NET Framework Data Provider for
>   ODBC does not support passing named parameters to an SQL statement or
>   to a stored procedure called by an OdbcCommand. In either of these
>   cases, use the question mark (?) placeholder.

Direct quote from here:

[named parameters with .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196416/select-query-does-not-work-with-parameters-using-parameters-addwithvalue)